# Uninstalled USB drivers on accident, now I can't access computer

Tags: windows-7, drivers

So my case's USB 2.0 ports have not been working lately, while the 3.0's have been and are right next to the 2's, so I decided to try to uninstall and reinstall all my USB drivers in device manager. I started uninstalling this one USB driver, and all of a sudden, neither my keyboard or mouse have been working.

I restarted, unplugged and replugged. That didn't work, it just says failed to install device drivers on boot up. The mouse and keyboard work fine in the BIOS and the Windows Recovery menu with the recovery disc. Anyway to reverse this? Thanks!

Comment: Haven't you tried system restore from recovery menu? Or using a ps/2 input device?

Comment: I don't have any other mice, and when using system restore, it says that I must specify which Windows installation to restore. I only have one and there's no operation systems showing up at the beginning to choose from. It does boot fine though...

Comment: How are you entering recovery menu? Press F8 at startup and select `Repair Computer`. It seems odd to prompt which windows installation to restore through this.

Comment: Repeatedly pressing F8 while booting hasn't worked since I installed Windows.

Comment: I just got a PS/2 mouse, tried "Scan for hardware changes", and it didn't work. But I downloaded the USB 3.0 driver for my motherboard and it finally worked. Thanks for the PS/2 tip

Answer (score 0):

I just got a PS/2 mouse, tried "Scan for hardware changes", and it didn't work. But I downloaded the USB 3.0 driver for my motherboard and it finally worked. Thanks for the PS/2 tip, @Bharat